# Show/Hide Div Elements based on dropdown entry

Tags: jquery

I have 4 Div elements, and a dropdown. If I select a dropdown option such as "2", `DivElement2` is shown and all others are hidden.

I want to change this, so that when I select option "2", both `DivElement1` and `DivElement2` are shown. I guess this would have to go through some loop function, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
<select name="Count">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement1">Div1</div>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement2">Div2</div>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement3">Div3</div>
<div class="CommonAttribute DivElement4">Div4</div>
```

---

This is the current jquery function that basically first adds hide to everything, and then removes it from the element it wishes to show.

```
if($(this).attr('name') == 'Count')
            {
                $('.CommonAttribute').addClass('hide');
                $('.DivElement' + $(this).val()).removeClass('hide');
            }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: So if you click 3 it shows div1, div2, and div3? Like that?

Comment: What should happen if option "3" is selected? and when option "4" is selected?

Comment: Hello. Nicolas is correct, and j08691 has already posted what I have wanted. Thanks for helping out everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No loop needed:

```
$('.CommonAttribute').hide();
$('select[name="Count"]').change(function () {
    $('.CommonAttribute').hide();
    $('.CommonAttribute:lt(' + $(this).val() + ')').show()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hk87V/)**

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! I would like to understand though, what is `.CommontAttribute:lt`, specifically the :lt part? Do we not need to use `DivElement#` anymore?

Comment: [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) is the less than selector (zero based). Basically it's saying select the first X `.CommonAttribute` elements here. You could use DivElement# as well, but then you'd need a loop to get the items less than X.

Comment: Thank you! I have been unable to make it work, however with all kinds of modifications to my code, so I have uploaded with that I have here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/1/. I notice that I get a `TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function` error, which is something I do not have, yet the code is exactly the same except for the missing `$(document).ready(function(){` in jsfiddle. Do you know what's wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**js**

```
$("select").on("change",
               function(){
                   $("div").hide();
                   show(parseInt($(this).val()));
               });

function show(counter){            
            for(var i=1; i<=counter; i++){
                $(".DivElement"+i).show();
            }
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4f8KW/5/)